# PHP 5 passing class Object as parameter, is it always a pointer or a copy or a clone?

Tags: php, scope

I have a question about passing object as parameter. When we pass a variable, it creates a copy, but looks like object is always a reference pointer, is this correct? I have tested with the following example code:

```
class Base 
{
    private $var;
    function set ($var)
    {
        $this->var = $var;
    }

    function show ()
    {
        echo $this->var, '<br>';
    }
}

class Car
{
    private $obj;
    function __construct($obj)
    {
        $this->obj = $obj;
    }

    function set ($var)
    {
        $this->obj->set($var);
    }

    function show()
    {
        $this->obj->show();
    }
}

class Bus
{
    private $obj;
    function __construct($obj)
    {
        $this->obj = $obj;
    }

    function set ($var)
    {
        $this->obj->set($var);
    }

    function show()
    {
        $this->obj->show();
    }
}
```

And by running

```
$base = new Base();
$base->set('one');
$base->show();          // one

$bus = new Bus($base);
$bus->show();           // one

$car = new Car($base);
$car->set('two');
$car->show();           // two

$base->show();          // two

$bus->show();           // two
```

The display result is:

```
one
one
two
two
two
```

So changing the Base class's variable anywhere even it was passed as parameter into a function or another class will affect all of them, so does this mean it's always pointing to a same object as a pointer?

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Comment: Objects are passed by references by default.
But actully, php reference isn't real reference and every time you pass an object the php proccesor create new object that are identical and if you change one it will change the another.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In PHP When you pass object as parameter, it is copy of the reference. So:

```
$ob = new StdClass;
$ob->var = "Lorem";

function aa($o) {
    $o->var="Ipsum";
}
aa($ob);
echo $ob->var;
```

this will output `Ipsum`, but if you assign other object to that $o reference:

```
function aa($o) {
    $o = new StdClass;
    $o->var="Ipsum";
}
```

It will output `Lorem` - because $ob still points to previously created object.

**By the way:**
If you change function definition to `function aa(&$o)`. Now it will output `Ipsum` again, because $o is reference to $ob reference :)

**To sum up:**
In PHP by default parameters are passed by value - also if they are objects! **But**! In code `$ob = new StdClass;`, `$ob` **is reference**  to the object. So by default we will pass copy of the reference. They will point to the same objects. But if you change passed variable (`$o = new StdClass;`), `$ob` still points to the same object. That's why after that modification given example will output `Lorem`.

You can pass parameters by reference using ampersand (&), but in case of objects it is usually useless.

Comment: In PHP 5 that is not correct, you do not need to pass objects with the & reference.

Comment: @Jessica It is only additional information so the answer is complete - I think I have given straightforward example. In most cases & is pointless, but if for some reason you have to change referring object (like in the second function) it is what we need.

Comment: @Andy Thank you for the detailed explanation! Have a great New Year!

Comment: executing the first code snippet is actually returning "Lorem" for me.

Comment: @MAB, thanks for pointing it out, luckily there wasn't a bug in code or the explaination, I simply forgot to actually execute `aa` function in code snipped. Added `aa($ob);` line :)